# VueJS wtith storyhot config for storybook and jest error of Cannot find module '@storybook/vue/dist/server/babel_config' from 'config-loader.js'

Tags: vue.js, babeljs, jestjs, storybook, storyshots

Reproduce
clone https://github.com/adamchenwei/vuejs-playground/tree/step/3-3-2-B-storybook-storyshot-broken
checkout step/3-3-2-B-storybook-storyshot-broken
`npm run test`

See error `Cannot find module '@storybook/vue/dist/server/babel_config' from 'config-loader.js'`
[image]

Where did I do wrong? I suspect something in babel, but I am not sure what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolve it by opening issue all over the github! It was a result of inconsistent storybook addon versions vs storybook version!

Please look at my commit here for the key configurations
https://github.com/adamchenwei/vuejs-storybook-storyshot-jest-webpack-boilerplate/commit/df9cc7cacb045633b20bb0ffad71abed31a81b73

Ignore all the fluffy in it, this piece is the key fix: by upgrade to same `4.0.0-rc.6`

[image]

Have fun coding!